# How can I prevent my Flutter code from generating errors in case a resource is not found when using url_launcher?

Tags: android, flutter, url-launcher

I have a code similar to this (just showing the point). The code works correctly and loads some pages. However, when I try to load an app from the PlayStore, it just shows an error stating that it cannot open the "intent" page. This page seems to load as a component. How can I make it so that, in case I get an error when loading certain components, the program ignores them and loads the web anyway?

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

final Uri _url = Uri.parse('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package-name>');


// Code to open the web

Future<void> _launchUrl() async {
  try {
    if (!await launchUrl(_url)) {
      throw Exception('Error $_url');
    }
  } catch (e) {
   // Error
  }
}
```

I tried adding the internet permission, which got it to work. However, then I ran into that issue. I tried adding a catch block, hoping that the web page would display even if some components were not found.

Comment: Have you tried passing different LaunchMode values to launchUrl?  https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher/launchUrl.html